# How C# generic works?

Tags: c#, generics, runtime, compile-time

C++ templates are generated at compile time. I heard that C# generics are generated at runtime. This mean that it is generated at the moment of IL -> execution? Is this part also included in the runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertions are correct, C++ templates are completely constructed at compilation, *.Net* creates the types it needs at run-time.  Although, generic typing needs to be resolved at compile time, the generated classes for the *MSIL* that get used and reused are generated at run-time (albeit slightly differently for Value Types and Reference Types)

[Differences Between C++ Templates and C# Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics)

> C# Generics and C++ templates are both language features that provide
>   support for parameterized types. However, there are many differences
>   between the two. At the syntax level, C# generics are a simpler
>   approach to parameterized types without the complexity of C++
>   templates. In addition, C# does not attempt to provide all of the
>   functionality that C++ templates provide. **At the implementation level,
>   the primary difference is that C# generic type substitutions are
>   performed at runtime and generic type information is thereby preserved
>   for instantiated objects**.

[Generics in the Run Time (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time)

**Value Types**

> When a generic type **is first constructed** with a value type as a
>   parameter, **the runtime creates a specialized generic type** with the
>   supplied parameter or parameters substituted in the appropriate
>   locations in the MSIL. Specialized generic types are created one time
>   for each unique value type that is used as a parameter.

**Reference Types**

> Generics work somewhat differently for reference types. **The first time
>   a generic type is constructed with any reference type**, **the runtime
>   creates a specialized generic type with object references substituted
>   for the parameters in the MSIL**. Then, every time that a constructed
>   type is instantiated with a reference type as its parameter,
>   regardless of what type it is, the runtime reuses the previously
>   created specialized version of the generic type. This is possible
>   because all references are the same size.